# Laravel Scheduled Task Only Runs when Logged In

Tags: php, laravel

I have a scheduled task in `Kernel.php` which calls a method called `cronCache` in `userController`. The scheduled task is run every minute in `Laravel Forge`

`Kernel.php`:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
//check cache every 1 min
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\userController@cronCache')
            ->everyMinute();
    }
```

`userController@cronCache`:

```
   public function cronCache() {

        $vw = Cache::remember('userCountCache',10,function(){


            return $query = DB::table('vwUserCount')->first();
        });

    }
```

This method caches a mySQL query and it runs successfully, but only when I'm logged in to my app. Once I log out the task stops running. When I log in again, the task continues to run again.

I have another method in `userController` which makes a cache of the same query if none exists when my view is loaded. I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm including it here:

```
public function showUserCache() {


        $vw = Cache::remember('userCountCache',3,function(){

            return $query = DB::table('vwUserCount')->first();
        });

        $userCount = $vw->userCount;
        return view ('backend.user_summary', compact('userCount'));


    }
```

Comment: What is the middleware on that route?  Is it protected?

Comment: Do you have the scheduler started `php artisan schedule:run` and how do you know that this cron runs only when you're logged?

Comment: @Rooneyl I haven't assigned any middleware to that route.

Comment: @TheFallen I am using DB::getQueryLog(); and printing the result on the view. It shows whether the view is querying the DB or using the cache. When I'm logged in it will successfully cache and refresh the cache for many hours. When I log out and log back in after the cache expires I can see that the DB is being queried in my log. Then it will start caching successfully and continue to refresh the cache as designed.